# Network interfaces not showing up on fresh Gentoo install

Tags: wifi, gentoo, internet, wpa-supplicant

After a fresh Gentoo install, my `ifconfig` is showing just my loopback. `ifconfig -a` returns all my interfaces. My `lspci -knn` shows my wireless card as loaded with `ath9k`, both the driver and module. Ethernet also has a driver.

I would like to connect via `wpa_supplicant` (wirelessly, duh). Config for it looks fine, followed the Gentoo wireless guide for that.

Here's my [PC](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03791266) if needed. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks, and cheers!

Comment: Try installing NetworkManager by chrooting form live usb. Check interfaces with ```ip link``` and ```nmcli r wi```. Post the output